# equal ints that return false

Tags: java, comparison, int, equals

I have a method that checks an int read in from aother method and compares it to its reverse. If the numbers are equal and thus a palindrome, true is returned. However, false keeps getting returned regardless of whether or not the number entered is a palindrome.

```
public class Paladin
{
    public static void main()
    {
        boolean valid;

        String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number to be reversed:   ");
        int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

        valid = isPalindrome(Reverse(inputInt));

        if(valid)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputInt + " is a palindrome");

        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputInt + " is not a palindrome");

        public static  boolean isPalindrome (int number)
        {
            int undoReverse = 0;

            while(number > 0)  
            {
                undoReverse = undoReverse * 10 + number % 10;
                number /= 10; 
            }

            if(number == undoReverse)
                return true;

            else 
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are modifying the input `number` in your `isPalindrome` method as mentioned below:

```
    number /= 10;
```

and hence your

```
if(number == undoReverse)
```

comparision is not happening with the input number, rather it is happening with the the modified number. You basically need to preserve this original number for comparison and use a different variable. Try this:

```
 public static  boolean isPalindrome (int number)
        {
            int undoReverse = 0;
            int inputNumber = number;

            while(number > 0)  
            {
                undoReverse = undoReverse * 10 + number % 10;
                number /= 10; 
            }

            if(inputNumber == undoReverse)
                   return true;

            else 
                return false;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop ends when `number <= 0`, but then you test if `number == undoReverse`.  You're modifying `number`, and then trying to test *the modified* value for equality.  Instead, you should be calculating `undoReverse` based on a *copy* of `number`.